# Iterating through a table and applying conditions, Python

Tags: python, conditional-statements

I have two tables Table 1 and Table 2. Table 1 has one column and Table 2 has two columns. I am giving below an example of my two tables to further explain what I am trying to do.

```
TABLE 1         TABLE 2
  A             B      C
 0.015         0.000  14.0      #The BINS are 0.00-0.01 = 14.0
 0.033         0.025  14.5                  # 0.01-0.02 = 14.5    
 0.042         0.050  15.0                  # 0.02-0.03 = 15.0 
 0.501         0.075  15.5                  # 0.03-0.04 = 15.5  AND SO ON
 0.505         0.100  16.0                    
 0.520         0.125  16.5
 0.350         0.150  17.0
```

**Here if we take BINS in column B, i.e 0.0 to 0.01 and 0.01 to 0.02 and so on.**

I would like to select the column A in Table 1, **take the first value (0.015) find out the range (BIN) in which it lies (we can see that it lies between 0.000 and 0.025),** and I would like to add a second column to table 1, and give it the value 14.5 (second BIN from table 2).

I would like to repeat the same for the second value of table 1, **i.e 0.033, we can see it lies between 0.025 and 0.050, so we give it value 15.5 (from table 2). and so on.**

The problem is, the only way I know to iterate is using for loops,

```
for a in A:  #takes the values of column A in table 1
```

But here I don't know how to proceed further. **i.e. How do I check which BIN of column B does my column A value lie?** so that I can give it the corresponding value from column C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate through a list using `for i, x in enumerate(X)`. This gives you both the element of the list and the index of that element. You could also use `for i in range(len(X))`, since in your case you may need to do a look-ahead. Maybe this will work for a solution with arbitrary bin sizes:

```
A2 = []
for a in A:
    for i in range(len(B)-1):
        if a < B[i+1]:
            A2.append(C[i])
            break
    else:    # We never broke out
        A2.append(C[-1])
```

We compare each element in `A` to progressively greater elements in `B`. If the element `a` is less than the value of a list element in `B`, then it belongs in the previous bin (i.e. `0.015` from `A` is less than `0.025` in `B` and thus belongs in the previous bin). A breakdown, since you asked:

```
A2 = []   # Make a new list
for a in A:   # Do the below once for every element in A
    for i in range(len(B)-1):
```

Instead of iterating directly over `B`, we're looping through the possible indexes (which start at `0` and end at `len(B)-1`). **However**, we're actually going one less than that. If you use `range(10)`, you end up with `0...9`. So if you want to iterate over all of `B`, you can just use `range(len(B))`. But we actually want to go one *less* than the full length of `B`, because in the next step, we're looking ahead.

```
        if a < B[i+1]:
```

Here we're looking one list index ahead, to see if `a` is less than the `B` element at index `i+1`. If it is, then we want to find the element of `C` that corresponds to the *previous* index, i.e. index `i`. For example, given `0.015` from list `A`, we look at `0.025` from `B`. `0.015 < 0.025`, so that means `0.015` belongs in the previous bin. That's why we're looking ahead by one.

```
            A2.append(C[i])
            break
```

Grab the element of `C` that corresponds to index `i` (no longer looking ahead, since we know `i` is the correct bin as `i+1` is too large) and toss it into `A2`. Then `break` out of the inner `for` loop and start again with the next element of `A`.

```
    else:    # We never broke out
        A2.append(C[-1])
```

This `else` statement executes if we never `break` out of the `for` loop. In this case, `a` can only possibly be in the final bin, so we just grab the element from `C` that's at the end of the list (which `[-1]` will do automatically).

Comment: Could you if possible run through the loop, as to what it does? especially the `break` and `else` bit?

Comment: Perfect and detailed explanation. Thanks

Comment: After appending the first value `A2.append(C[i])`, does the loop start again from the beginning, i.e from `for a in A:`??

Comment: @ThePredator `break` will stop the _innermost_ for loop in its tracks, and here that's the loop iterating over `B`. The `for a in A` loop will move on to the next element in `A`, since the code inside that `for` loop is done for that iteration.

Answer (score 2):

You can just multiply `a` by 40 and then convert it to int and use that as the index in table 2.

For example, take the first value (0.015) and multiply it by 40 (0.6) and convert it to int (0) and you have the index in table 2 that you want.

```
D = list()
for a in A:
    index = int(a*40)
    try:
        corresponding_value_from_c = C[index]
    except IndexError:
        corresponding_value_from_c = C[-1]
    D.append(correspondin_value_from_c)
```

At the end, D will be the column containing all the values that you need.

Comment: Since my column B has 89 rows, will this work if I multiply by 89 instead of 100??

Comment: You mean the values in column B are not growing with 0.01 from one to the next? are there bigger leaps?

Comment: The values in column B do from with the same leap. There are no bigger leaps! But My values in column A have higher values, say 1.0 for example. `1.0x100=100`, but there is no index 100 in column B

Comment: Ok. And what would you like to do for 1.0? Give it the corresponding value in the last row in the second table?

Comment: No, my column B in second table starts from 0.000 and increases in steps of 0.025 all the way to 2.200. So there are 89 rows from 0.000 to 2.200.

Comment: I have modified the answer. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59947/discussion-between-thepredator-and-ionut-hulub).